# Как целесообразнее разрабатывать приложение под ios?

Tags: xcode, ios

Все добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Нужно разработать простое приложение под айфон и айпад, будет авторизация, несколько сцен (окон) с кнопками, нажимая на которые будут отправляться запросы к серверу.

Вопрос, как проще всего разработать это приложение, учитывая, что опыта разработки под айос нет?

Использовать storybroad или нет? (в интернете больше примеров без него)

Нужно поддержка, начиная с 5 версии айос, какие подводные камни?

Буду очень благодарен за советы!

Answer (score 2):

storyboard - очень удобная штука для разработки простых приложений, но в тоже время наиубогоющее изобретение для сложных приложений. Достаточно прочитать в любой книге про сторибоарды и можно клипать приложение. Но авторизация и прочие штуки нужно будет изучать. Сейчас уже давольно много библиотек которые позволяют это делать за несколько кусочков кода. Но надо это все усваивать, в любом случае. Что косается 5 ос, есть ньюансы по поводу поворота вьюх... но это уже отдельная тема.

Comment: А допустима ли такая ситуация: наклепать простое приложение, используя storyboard, а в дальнейшем, сложные вещи, реализовывать без него? 

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Нет. Придется с нуля наследовать классы и руками прописывать координаты и размеры вьюх. Я думаю это главный недостаток сторибоардов, то что их фиг потом кастомизируешь. Нужно будет все выколупывать из super класса.

Comment: допустима. 
можете использовать как сториборды так и нибы в одном проекте.
если приложение простое, его и на нибах просто сделать будет. 
5ось не поддерживает autolayout при перевороте девайса.
это не может не печалить, т.к. это приличный кусок работы.

Comment: Но как показывает практика, все придется удалить и написать с нуля на чистом Objective-c

Comment: Господа) Что вы в результате порекомендуете, если в дальнейшем в приложении планируется чат? нибы или сториборд?

Comment: xib nib storyboard все гавно что. :) Если сроки жмут, однозначно юзайте сторибоарды или nib xib что удобнее и быстрее для Вас. Но было бы не плохо парарельно создавать проект на чистых классах без этих XML-ных каркасов. Вы будете понимать всю сущьность objective-c взаимодейтсвие объектов и это даст преемущество в будущей его доработке. Сторибоарды рефакторить ваще не вариант.
Резюмируя:
StoryBoard лучше xib и темболее nib файлов. - Используйте для прототипа, рабочего прототипа, он может даже выйти в продакеш. Но один раз. Не масштабируемый комок говнокода.